# How to access variables created in __init__ in another def in the same instance of a class?

Tags: python, class, init

Goal: Being able to access `a` in `play`.

Note: I need to save information via variables in the same instance of the class because `play` will be called multiple times.

Code:

```
class something():
    def __init__(self):
        a = 2

    def play(self, b):
        return True if a == b else False

test = something()
print(test.play(1))
```

Expectations: It should `print False` because `2 != 1`, but I get this error instead:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

I've tried:

- Getting rid of `__init__` and just putting the int outside a def.
- Setting up the int before `__init__` and just accessing it in `__init__`.

Note: I can't pass arguments to `__init__` while making a new instance of the class, this is for an exercise, which can be found [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/587136ba2eefcb92a9000027), and I don't control the creation of a new instance.

Comment: Do I have to use `self.a` while creating the variable inside `__init__`  as well? Or should I only use it when I'm calling the variable inside `play`? And thank you so much! :)

Comment: Sidenote, `True if boolean else False` is the same as `boolean`, so it's simpler to do `return a == b`

Comment: Did you mean to comment on @KnowledgeGainer's answer?

Comment: @isuckatcoding I didn't notice that you didn't use `self` inside `__init__` function while writing my comment. That's why I deleted it. Yes, you need to use `self` while defining variables inside `__init__` if you want to access them later.

Comment: This is an *absurdly* basic question; you need to run through [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and actually learn the language before you start doing coding challenges in a language. You're not going to learn it asking trivial questions one by one on SO, and you shouldn't be wasting people's time asking them to rewrite the tutorial for you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, it's simple but at least it's properly formatted and answerable which is uncommon among "New contributor"s.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Apologies, I tried my best to find an answer before posting it here, but I wasn't able to, which is indeed my bad. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2

    def play(self, b):
        return True if self.a == b else False

test = something()
print(test.play(1))
```

In the `__init__` you have to use **`self.variable`** and same can be used in other functions too of same class.